# 500 internal error - 200 via fiddler

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have when a service responds (when they send a response) to my .net mvc action.

I am doing a post request via fiddler:
POST HTTP/1.1
Url: https://website.com/Order/Response

Headers:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: website.com
Content-Length: 174

Request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MerchantNotification><OrderID>635605588006228888</OrderID><MerchPayMethod>CC</MerchPayMethod><Status>OK</Status></MerchantNotification>
```

When I do request to our server via fiddler I get HTTPS/200 OK, but when 
their server sends the same response (post request basically, response) I get Internal 500 error. I am using Azure, how can I resolve what is basically wrong?

Do I have to use Azure Power Shell, and how to resolve this 500 internal error. It's first time experience for me, and when I do it via fiddler I get 200 OK, so It's kind of hard for me to resolve this.

Azure Log:

> 2015-02-27 15:26:33 website.com POST /Order/Response
>   X-ARR-LOG-ID=dabac80f-dcca-4476-9550-bb8fd2fefe33 443 - 78.24.211.75
>   Apache-HttpClient/4.2+(java+1.5) - - website.com 500 0 0 12574 979 968

Comment: What is the error message? do you have control over the server?

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: The error message just shows 500. Which I don't know how to debug on Azure.

2015-02-27 15:26:33 website.com POST /Order/Response X-ARR-LOG-ID=dabac80f-dcca-4476-9550-bb8fd2fefe33 443 - 78.24.211.75 Apache-HttpClient/4.2+(java+1.5) - - website.com 500 0 0 12574 979 968